# I am trying to find the height of a Binary tree with this code, but it keeps returning 0, can someone tell me why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree

I am trying to find the height of a Binary tree with this code, but it keeps returning 0, can someone please tell me why?

```
int heightHelper(Node* root, int maxheight, int rootheight)
{

    if (root->right == nullptr && root->left == nullptr) { //checks if the node has a child
        if (maxheight < rootheight) {
            maxheight = rootheight;
        }
    }
    else { //if it has then increase height by 1
        rootheight += 1;

        if (root->left != nullptr) {
            heightHelper(root->left, maxheight, rootheight);
        }
        if (root->right != nullptr) {
            heightHelper(root->right, maxheight, rootheight);
        }
    }

    return maxheight; //return height
}

int height(Node* root)
{
    // Write your code here.

    return heightHelper(root, 0, 0); //root node base case
}
```

Comment: There is no single oversight here. This entire algorithm is fundamentally wrong. The correct solution involves a simple recursive function that takes only a single parameter, the node in the tree, and it returns the maximum height of the tree. No need to pass any additional parameters. Going over it in my mind, it's about five lines of code (not counting the function declaration). One if statement. Two recursive calls. And a ternary operator on the returned value (or a `std::max` call, maybe). That's it. If you write anything more than that, it'll be wrong.

Comment: You call `heightHelper` recursively, but ignore its return value. That call is then useless - the function doesn't have any side effects, its return value is the only benefit it provides.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that `maxheight` should potentially be altered following a recursive call to `heightHelper()`. You *could* arrange for that; read up on [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up two ways of doing things. Either *pass the result parameter*, using a pointer or an address (`int*` and `&maxheight`). In this case there is no return value. But tbh, this is a coding style I've mainly only seen in hardware programming.

Otherwise you can return a result. You already have a return parameter in place, just fix the actual usage of the value because your code ignores it.

Here's the two ways to do it:

Using return parameter:

```
int heightHelper(Node* root, int height)
{

    if (root->right == nullptr && root->left == nullptr) { //checks if the node has a child
        return height;
    }
    else { //if it has then increase height by 1
        height += 1;
        int maxheight1;
        int maxheight2;

        if (root->left != nullptr) {
            maxheight1 = heightHelper(root->left, height);
        }
        if (root->right != nullptr) {
            maxheight2 = heightHelper(root->right, height);
        }

        // return maximum of the two
        if (maxheight1 > maxheight2) return maxheight1;
        else return maxheight2;
    }
}

int height(Node* root)
{
    // Write your code here.

    return heightHelper(root, height); //root node base case
}
```

Using pointer parameters. Note that rootheight is local to each branch so don't pass it as a pointer.

```
void heightHelper(Node* root, int* maxheight_ptr, int rootheight)
    {

    if (root->right == nullptr && root->left == nullptr) { //checks if the node has a child
        if (*maxheight < rootheight) {
            *maxheight = rootheight;
        }
    }
    else { //if it has then increase height by 1
        rootheight += 1;

        if (root->left != nullptr) {
            heightHelper(root->left, maxheight_ptr, rootheight);
        }
        if (root->right != nullptr) {
            heightHelper(root->right, maxheight_ptr, rootheight);
        }
    }
}

int height(Node* root)
{
    // Write your code here.

    int maxheight = 0;


    heightHelper(root, &maxheight, 0); //pass the addresses of variables

    return maxheight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I wanted to do I missed the reference part, I know my mistake now.